# TCP IP Client/Server failing to connect

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a small TCP Client server application that cannot seem to connect and is giving a timeout error and I can figure out why.

The error I am getting is

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond 161.242.249.63:5000    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)

Below are the list of steps I have tried:

1. tried both client and server applications on the same PC, this will work, but if the applications are on different machines than I cant seem to get a connection due to a timeout.
2. I can ping both PC's by name and IP address.  IPv6 has also been disabled.   The PCs are linked by Cat5e Ethernet cable over about half a meter.
3. I have Checked all firewall rules and allowed traffic on port 5000 on both PCs
4. On CMD i have confirmed the port is listening using netstat -a
5. using Putty, I can telnet from either machine and make a connection to the server

I am not sure why i cant make a connection from my client application

Server Code

```
//string IP = ServerSocket.getIP();
        string IP = "161.242.249.63";

        IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        Console.WriteLine("IP Address is :" + IP);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, 5000);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            //---incoming client connected---
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            //---read incoming stream---
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            //---convert the data received into a string---
            string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received");
            string[] data = dataReceived.Split(',');
            data[2]= data[2].Remove(data[2].Length-1);
            bool validate = ValidateAgainstADAndGroup(data[0], data[1], data[2]);

            if (validate)
            {
                byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("*");
                //---write back the text to the client---
                Console.WriteLine("Sending back : OK " );
                nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                client.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("!");
                //---write back the text to the client---
                Console.WriteLine("Sending back : Error");
                nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                client.Close();

            }
```

Client Code

```
 TcpClient client = new TcpClient("10.248.37.62", 5000);
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        //send data
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        //---read back the text---
        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        // Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
        client.Close();
```

I would be greatful if anyone could help with this?

Comment: what exactly does the error message say, please? Show the error message and stack trace (and point out to us which line in your code causes it, since we can't see your line numbers). This should be the minimum info provided when reporting an error. just because it seems obvious to you, doesn't necessarily make it obvious to everyone reading. (I can guess of course, but that's not the point.)

Comment: @ADyson, you are absolutely correct,  I have added the error now   -  I have amended the op with the error I am receiving.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a networking problem as there is nothing inherently wrong with the code provided.

It does look like youre trying to bind the server to the public IP address though which isnt correct as the system doesnt know what its own IP address is.

You should bind it to a network interface or use `IPAddress.Any`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.any?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: Thanks Kieran, what I have found is that on the first attempt to connect , it will always fail. But will connect on the second attempt... Not sure why it times out the first time... There is no other traffic on the network

Comment: Is this also the case if you start the server, wait 15 seconds and then start the client?

Comment: Yes, it happens no matter how long I wait.